# Compare Integers between Lists in a Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I am trying to make a calculator for a game. I would like to get the max integer at a specific index between lists (that are values in the dictionary) and the key that the max value came from.

I've tried to loop through the dictionary.

```
raw_player_score = {'Matt' : [3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 9],
                    'Kyle' : [6, 9, 11, 5, 4, 3],
                    'Emily' : [4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5]}

def extra_points(dict):
    for k, v in dict.items():
        for number in v:
            apple_king = max(v[1])
            print(apple_king)

final_dict = extra_points(raw_player_score)
```

I would expect the outcome to be 9 since Kevin has the highest number at index 1, but instead, I get the message "'int' object is not iteratable'

Comment: Pseudocode: NameError - this does not work as is. Please fix your [mre] to be python.

Comment: Kevin? Who's Kevin?

Comment: `max(v[1])` doesn't make any sense because `v[1]` is a single integer. You need to build up a secondary list from the lists in the dictionary before calling `max()`.

Comment: Where `dx = 1` code `max((vals[dx], name) for (name, vals) in raw_player_score.items())` gives `(9, 'Kyle')`. Ties would be decided by reverse alphabetical order of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the suggestions in the other answers are spot on. I'll offer up a simpler, old-school solution that does the minimal amount of work, not having to create any additional lists or do any sorting.  I figure that as a new Python programmer, you might be best served by the most direct and transparent approach:

```
raw_player_scores = {'Matt' : [3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 9],
                    'Kyle' : [6, 9, 11, 5, 4, 3,],
                    'Emily' : [4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5]}

def extra_points(scores, pos):
    max_score = 0
    max_key = None
    for k, v in scores.items():
        if v[pos] > max_score:
            max_score = v[pos]
            max_key = k
    return max_key

max_key = extra_points(raw_player_scores, 1)
print(max_key)
```

Result:

```
Kyle
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to hardcode the needed index; I recommend you to move it to an argument. Other changes are commented:

```
def extra_points(dict_, index):
    return max(                                    # Return maximum
        (                                          # From iterator
            (name, score_list[index])              # For name-score[index] tuples
            for name, score_list in dict_.items()  # In dict_
        ),
        key=lambda x: x[1]                         # Check the max by score[index]
    )[0]                                           # Get the name (zero element)

raw_player_score = {
    'Matt': [3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 9],
    'Kyle': [6, 9, 11, 5, 4, 3,],
    'Emily': [4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5]
}

print(extra_points(raw_player_score, 1))
```

> `Kyle`

Comment: Your solution has a lot more changes than just passing the index as a param.

Comment: `return max(dict_, key=lambda name: dict_[name][index])`

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use dict as a variable name, you can try:

```
raw_player_score = {'Matt': [3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 9], 'Kyle': [6, 9, 11, 5, 4, 3], 'Emily': [4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5]}


def extra_points(d, ind):
    values_at_index = []
    for key in d:
        values_at_index.append((key, d[key][ind]))
    return max(values_at_index, key=lambda x: x[1])


print(extra_points(raw_player_score, 1))
print(extra_points(raw_player_score, 1)[0])
```

which gives:

```
('Kyle', 9)
Kyle
```

Comment: `def extra_points(d, ind): return max((v[ind], k) for (k, v) in d.items())`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, cool one liner :) Maybe post an answer to make it easier for viewers to see.

Comment: You are making an intermediate list `values_at_index` which is verbose, unneeded, and makes your code less readable.  Also not using a list comprehension for creating `values_at_index` makes your code non-idiomatic. The point is not to make a one-liner.  It's one line because that's the complexity of the problem.

Comment: The same way the code doesn't need to be a one-liner, the code doesn't have to NOT have a list. I chose to code it this way. I hope your day gets a little better.